# How can I read values from a buffer with Numpy when some bytes are padded?

Tags: python, numpy, pyserial

Currently I am using a sensor that constantly provides information by using serial port. The data read and saved in the buffer is for example:

```
b'\x00\x009\x00A\x002\x00\x00\x18\x00\x13\x00\x11\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x11'
```

I have been using numpy in order to convert the buffers into arrays I can iterate over.

```
byteVec = np.frombuffer(byteBuffer, dtype = 'uint8')
```

But doing this on the example results in the following array:

```
[95 0 0 57 0 65 0 50 0 0 24 0 19 0 17 0 16 0 16 0 16 0 16 0 17]
```

As you can see most of the data is read correctly except the values that come with an extra zero to the left like x009, x00A or x002. I do not know the reason why some values are being read like that in the first place since the pyserial port is programed to only accept sequences of 8 bits, is there a way for me to read those bytes with padded bits using numpy? or the problem lies with the serial port readings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't "padded" bytes. `\x009` is *two* bytes - a byte with value 0, and a byte with value 57, which happens to correspond to the ASCII code for a `9` character. Most bytes that correspond to printable ASCII values are displayed as the corresponding ASCII characters in the `repr` of a bytestring.

`np.frombuffer` is doing exactly what you want. (There's a mysterious extra `95` in the output you displayed, but that's either an error you introduced when composing your question, or the result of an unrelated bug you didn't show us.)

Comment: That's probably more helpful and better explained than my answer  I didn't think to spell it out like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me:

```
byteBuffer = b'\x00\x009\x00A\x002\x00\x00\x18\x00\x13\x00\x11\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x11'

np.frombuffer(byteBuffer, dtype = 'uint8')
```

**Output**

```
array([ 0,  0, 57,  0, 65,  0, 50,  0,  0, 24,  0, 19,  0, 17,  0, 16,  0,
   16,  0, 16,  0, 16,  0, 16,  0, 17], dtype=uint8)
```